# how to binarize float values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network

I have float data like this which is a neural network output produced by 3 neurons. I want to convert to binary categorical labels (mutually exclusive) depending on the maximum row value.

```
0.423201  0.368718 0.338091
 0.246899  0.437535 0.000262
 0.978685 0.136219  0.027693
```

and output should be

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

This means each row can have value 1 once in a row, rest all zeros (maximum value becomes 1).

How to do it in pandas or python? I know get_dummies in pandas is the way to go but it is not working.

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) and then compare it with max value of `df1`. Last convert boolean `DataFrame` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to `int`:

```
print df
          0         1         2
0  0.423201  0.368718  0.338091
1  0.246899  0.437535  0.000262
2  0.978685  0.136219  0.027693

df1 = df.rank(method='max', axis=1)
print df1
   0  1  2
0  3  2  1
1  2  3  1
2  3  2  1

#get max value of df1
ma = df1.max().max()
print ma
3.0

print (df1 == ma)
       0      1      2
0   True  False  False
1  False   True  False
2   True  False  False

print (df1 == ma).astype(int)
   0  1  2
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
```

**EDIT**:

I think you can use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for comparing by rows with [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) of `df` and last convert by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to `int`:

```
print df.max(axis=1)
0    10
1     8
2     9
dtype: int64

print df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
   0  1  2
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
```

**Timings**

`len(df) = 3`:

```
In [418]: %timeit df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
The slowest run took 5.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop

In [419]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x == x.max(), axis='columns').astype(int)
The slowest run took 4.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

In [420]: %timeit (df.rank(method='max', axis=1) == df.rank(method='max', axis=1).max().max()).astype(int)
The slowest run took 4.83 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 656 µs per loop
```

`len(df) = 3000`:

```
In [426]: %timeit df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
The slowest run took 5.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 456 µs per loop

In [427]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x == x.max(), axis='columns').astype(int)
1 loops, best of 3: 496 ms per loop

In [428]: %timeit (df.rank(method='max', axis=1) == df.rank(method='max', axis=1).max().max()).astype(int)
The slowest run took 4.50 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
```

Comment: I try `df.rank(method='max', axis=0)`, but output is different. If you check [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html), `Ranks over columns (0) or rows (1)`

Comment: I add faster solution to my answer.

Comment: @jezrael I stand corrected. I tried to get rid of the `.apply()` without success and in the end its overhead outweighed the advantages of not using `rank()`.

Comment: Hmmm, I never use second solution if you not add answer. Thank you. But it is interesting `rank` is still faster (but not simpler) as `apply` approach.

Comment: @jezrael looks like rank is faster for small dataframes but scales worse. That makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be simpler and faster.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x == x.max(), axis='columns').astype(int)
```